# How to calculate whether a ray intersects an arbitrarily oriented bounding box?

Tags: linear-algebra

The bounding box is not axis-aligned. It can be rotated. I now have the origin of the ray, and direction and each coordinate of the eight vertices of the bounding box. what can I do to find out this ray intersects the box. I include the link to show the the picture describing what the situation below. The left is the box that aligns with the three major axis. The other is arbitrarily oriented. Thanks.

https://plus.google.com/113991334445378904468/posts/JyBkJhLCwL6?hl=zh_TW&pid=6150588663712344642&oid=113991334445378904468

Comment: Is it a rectangular box?

Comment: Yes. Each side is of unit length.

Comment: Find the equations for the planes through the sides of the box (e.g. using the three points). Then find the points of intersections of the ray and the planes (solving systems of three equations) and check if these are on the sides (check inequalities w/the planes equations and the coordinates of the vertices to make sure they're at the same half-spaces of the dividing planes). There's a cool problem of finding trajectoty of a ray reflecting in a box...